# Setting up API Gateway with Route 53 and Dynamodb global tables

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an application that uses Dynamodb as persistence layer and api gateway as interface to the internet. To make it globally accessible with the least amount of latency for the consumers of the api, I thought about enable Dynamodb global tables for various regions, deploy my api to the same regions and have Route 53 route traffic with an geolocation routing policy to the nearest api end point.
My questions are:

1. Is that the right way to do it? Am I missing something? Are there better ways?
2. What are the cost implications? As far as I understand are all services (Route 53, Dynamodb, API gateway) billed based on consumption. Therefore deploying to all regions does not add costs
   Thank you

**Update**

I set up the described infrastructure myself and document everything in a blog post. Please find it here: https://blog.taskli.st/posts/api-gateway-dynamodb-global-tables-route-53-latency-based-routing-policy

Answer (score 0):

1. You are perhaps missing a Lambda to interact with DynamoDB.  Not sure about your use case -- and it is not unheard of to expose DynamoDB directly -- but the most obvious pattern would be API Gateway -> Lambda -> DynamoDB.  But, as I say, your particular use case will drive that -- would be keen to learn more, if you want to share.
2. There are no particular [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/provisioned/) call-outs at this level of detail, as long as you are sure you want to run DynamoDB Global Tables.  You may consider provisioned capacity for DynamoDB, if you have stable consumption, but note that provisioned Global Tables are charged by hour.

There are probably like a hundred more questions I would ask about your solution architecture, but this is perhaps not the right forum.  Hope this much helps.

Comment: Using Lambda goes hand in hand with using Api Gateway for me. But you are right I should have mentioned that too. 
I found in the mean time that there are replicated write request units (rWCU) for every region that you want to replicate DynamodDB to. And they are actually more expensive than the standard WCU. https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/